# Regression model for a continuous dependent variable with count independent variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am currently working on a project where I have to estimate the average processing time of different work items (tasks).

**I have the following panel data:**

My sample size is n=2000 individual workers, and T=10 (each time interval is a four week period)

- Independent variables: 51 different work items.  I have count data for each work item (# of times they are performed by each worker over a four week period)
- Dependent variable: Total Working Hour of the worker (over a 4 week period)

The goal of my analysis is to find the regression coefficents (which are estimâtes of the average completion time of each work item).  I may also include other regressors (other than #of work items) such as experience, age... into my model.

y= Bo + B1*X1 +...+BkXk +e       y: total working hours;  X: # of work items

**Issues:**

Right now, I finished cleaning and processing the data and I performed some exploratory data analysis.

1. Some work items have a lot of zeros (the work item is only performed once or twice by several workers in the time period).
2. From VIF, I can see that there are imperfect multicollinearity in the independent variables.  Some independent variables have VIF of 5 to 6.

**Questions:**

1. Any advice on how I should specify my model?

I look at boxplots and eliminate outliers of each regressor,  I see that some regressors are highly skewed (due to lots of zéros).

I also plot each regressors against the total complétion time to see if there is any linear relation. So do, other looks more like a quadratic relation.

2. Any way to deal with the multicollinearity aside from eliminating the regressors that have high VIF?  This is because I need to estimate the coefficent of each of the work item.
3. Should I set the intercept to 0?  I know for sure that when ALL the regressors are 0 (# of work items are all 0, I should have zero total working hours).

I would also welcome any advice/things that I should look into for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I think this belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). What is your goal in doing this analysis?  To predict working hours, or to identify work items that take a long time, or to accurately quantify work per item in general, or ... ? Are all (or most) workers observed in all (or most) time periods?

Comment: Thanks I will post it over there also.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to 1) estimate the average hours it takes complete each work item (the regression coeff), and 2) Once we have a linear model, I can also predict y (the total working hours, given the X's the # of work item for a worker)

Comment: Yes almost all workers are observed in all time periods; thus I can use panel data to eliminate unobservable effects later on.  So far, I have only been analyzing data of one time period.